# Python selenium redirect page to after logging in a Webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium for automating a form filling. For this, I have to first login, then navigate to another page after logging in (or browse from the list of sectional wise options of Webportal and then search from list of IDs). I am successfully able to login but unable to change url to the required page which I wish to browse and land.

Is there a way how to browse and navigate through the sectional tabs after login page is opened. It might be difficult to browse(as it is deep inside nested sections) and that is why I am directly trying to give URL to the required ID which I want to open.

When I use

> `WebDriverWait(driver,DELAY)`
>
> `driver.get(desired_URL)`

to navigate after login, it automatically makes me end up on the homepage before logging in. I also tried *another Method*

> `WebDriverWait(driver,DELAY).until(driver.get(desired_URL))`

. This gives me an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Nothing worked for me. But actually this should not happen. After successful login, it should navigate to the page which I specify in `driver.get(desired_URL)` . I know in javascript there is a particular option like `driver.navigate().to(<desiredURL>)`. But I am using Python for my automation.

I would be really greatful for any of your helpful leads in solving my problem.

Comment: Does that approach you're trying to implement work if you do everything manually?

Comment: Yes absolutely.. It works. I can also search it by entering the ID in search box and click the link on the result found . But the URL remains unchanged. It remains the same. But the page navigates to the required ID field

Comment: I think you want a sleep here... or wait for an expected condition that appears after logging in.  If you login and then change the URL, you will probably navigate away before the login happens.  (the server looks up your username/password, confirms, then sends something to the browser to store... usually a cookie... this all takes a little bit of time.)  Your webdriverwait is failing because Until method will expect a bool or a webelement to be returned.  .get() does not return anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @pcalkins.. This helped me. I really  appreciate your help.. I was assuming "WebDriverWait(driver,DELAY)" is doing my wait function. But actually sleep is what making the execution pause. I am still little inclear about why Webdriverwait is not working. But I understand that "sleep" totally pauses the execution but where as Webdriver wait might not pause, but not sure what it exactly means by wait.

Comment: it'll poll the DOM for a certain expected condition to appear.  (a loop with a bunch of little 1/2 second sleeps in there... it'll ignore certain exceptions): https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explanation @pcalkins..